# Will a separate database multi tenant application work on Azure?

Tags: azure, cloud, azure-sql-database, multi-tenant

I've read that Azure has a 150GB database limit, and a limit of having 149 separate databases. If I understand this correctly, Azure would not be a good option if my app is using a separate DB setup where I have 1000+ different databases.

Am I right on this one or did I misinterpret Azure's limitations?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Azure's SQL Database is *database-as-a-service*. Each server you allocate has the individual database limit you mentioned, and you can create multiple servers, each with their own databases. So you can, indeed, go beyond 149 databases if you split the load across multiple servers. Or... you can manage tenancy in your app, storing multiple tenants within one logical database.

If you needed finer-grain control and wanted to manage databases yourself, you could always run SQL Server in a virtual machine (or multiple Vms, in an always-on configuration). At this point, you can configure the server any way you want to, and have up to 16TB attached storage (via 16 1TB mounted disks, all backed by durable blob storage).

In the Virtual Machines gallery, you'll see pre-built VMs with SQL Server installed. Once you deploy, you'd be responsible for maintaining the VM's (vs SQL-as-a-Service which takes care of all maintenance for you).

Comment: Is the limit different for MySQL databases? Besides that, deploying a new SQL instance after reaching 150 db's might be a problem and can get pricey quickly. My tenant DB's are really small (500-5000 records combined over all tables). Wouldn't rackspace hosting be a better option?

Comment: I'm ignoring your question on Rackspace; it's unrelated and opinion-soliciting. For smaller databases, [Azure SQL DB](http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/pricing/details/sql-database/) starts at $5 / monthly for up to 100MB, $10 monthly for up to 1GB. If that's too expensive, then combine tenants into a single DB (since pricing is scaled, not linear, costing less for larger DBs). Or just deploy your own server. Azure doesn't provide MySQL - ClearDB does through the Azure Store. You'll need to check their pricing. If you host MySQL in a VM, the limits and cost are the same as SQL Server.

Comment: Ah ok thx :) I asked about rackspace because I thought they had different limitations/setups regarding DB's

Comment: One thing I do is combine tenants into a single database. So I might have 100 in each database with a limit of 150 databases per server I could get up to 15,000 users (at which point I retire).

Comment: And one way to combine multiple tenants in a database is to use schema separation: http://geekswithblogs.net/hroggero/archive/2011/10/05/solving-schema-separation-challenges.aspx.  This project provides a complete example for a Compress Shard, which is what you may want to consider: http://enzosqlshard.codeplex.com/